# Enhanced 3D Cursor addon causes problem with the script search path

Tags: add-on

I installed a fresh new 2.75a version and the first addon I installed is the [Enhanced 3d cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor). But it has a error message that comes in every time I go to the addon tab of the user preference.
The add on runs smooth with no other problems.
I have not installed other addons so what can I do to fix this or is this a known problem that is reported on the list?

Comment: can you cut n paste error text from console, or add a screenshot to question please.

Comment: I've installed [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dairin0d/enhanced-3d-cursor/master/space_view3d_enhanced_3d_cursor.py) for testing purposes. No errors with 2.75a on linux.